# Regular expression to remove specific special characters

Tags: regex, expression

This is my string:

```
{"results":[{"Id":96,"Value":"DR - SUD OUEST"},{"Id":188,"Value":"MAGASIN - AUBAGNE"},{"Id":263,"Value":"MAGASIN - BONDY"},{"Id":289,"Value":"MAGASIN - CASTRES"}]}
```

I want to remove `"results"` and all special characters, except the `-`,`:` and `,` characters.

At the end I must have:

```
Id:96,Value:DR - SUD OUEST,Id:188,Value:MAGASIN - AUBAGNE,Id:263,Value:MAGASIN - BONDY,Id:289,Value:MAGASIN - CASTRES
```

How do I achieve that?

Comment: looks like JSON to me..

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: ...and tell us which characters you consider to be "special" - there's no common definition for that.